# Download group of files from server to client machine ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can't figure out how to let the user browse for a directory on their local machine and download some files from the server in my ASP.NET web application. Here is my code which at the moment hard codes to the documents folder. I want the user to be able to choose a folder and download the whole bunch of files though. Why can't I use the OpenFileDialog in VB.NET in order to let them select a folder?

```
Protected Sub materialsClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim materialsButton As Button = sender
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(materialsButton.Attributes("RowIndex"))
    Dim presentationDate As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(gvPresentations.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
    Dim format As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    Dim convertedDate As String = presentationDate.ToString(format)
    Dim dir As String = "\" + gvPresentations.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(0).Text & "\" & convertedDate
    Dim publisherDir As String = "D:\Presentations" & dir

    If Directory.Exists(publisherDir) Then
        Dim materials() As String = Directory.GetFiles(publisherDir)
        Dim newDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + dir
        messageLabel.Text = newDir

        Try
            If Not Directory.Exists(newDir) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newDir)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            messageLabel.Text = "Could not download materials"
        End Try

        For Each material As String In materials
            Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(material)

            If Not File.Exists(newDir & "\" & fileName) Then
                File.Copy(material, newDir & "\" & fileName)
            End If
        Next

        messageLabel.Text = "All files have been saved to " + newDir
    Else
        messageLabel.Text = "No materials available for this presentation"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Even what you already have doesn't do what you think it does. It only even seems to work for the hard-coded folder because the web browser where you're testing this is the same machine as the web server. Hint: if you're calling `.Exists()` or `File.Copy()` to do this, you're going about it the wrong way.

Comment: How do I do it the right way?

Comment: Remember that you're still using http... everything is about requests and responses. You **must** write a file to the response for the request you're working on. Additionally, you can only make one response per request. That means you need javascript to make a seprate request for each file you need to download. Finally, the web browser sandbox will almost certainly prevent you from achieving what you really want, because it will force a new file download pop-up for _each_ file. There is no way to circumvent this sandbox.

Comment: What the dickens? Why can't you just pop up a save file dialog or zip up the files and have them all go down the tubes at once? Who designed things that way? I still think in traditional desktop application terms (came from a C++ background to the wild web world) and don't get this http stuff. Is there no way to zip up the files and send them down the tubes?

Comment: You _could_ create a zip file for a single request. But you _can't_ unzip it automatically on the client.

Comment: The client can do that, that's fine. But what I am really looking for is some code. Any idea how to code what you're suggesting?